# RegExp how to select text with non-structural html elements?

Tags: html, regex, text

I'd like to select text from each line(\n\r\t and useless \s at te begining/end of the line can't be marked) in a file with "inline" html tags(with attributies) like

```
<b></b> <i></i> <span></span> <strong></strong> <font></font> etc...
```

from text, and leave not marked other "structural" html tags like

```
<a></a> <h1></h1> <br /> <img /> <div></div> <p></p> <header></header> <main></main> <footer></footer> etc...
```

Any ideas how to break this?

Comment: Definitely not with regex. And not just because trying to do it with regex will bring about the apocalypse, but because it's simply not achievable through using it alone.

Comment: Just use a string search for "inline", no need for regex.